# Opera max-height bug within position:absolute+overflow:auto element?

Tags: css, overflow, opera, css-position, w3c

I have recently encountered an issue in Opera, where it attempts to display scrollbar on a position:absolute+overflow:auto parent, when the child element has more content but with max-height set.

To illustrate the scenario, view this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kMZKm/12/

Changing the positioned element to have a fixed height, or changing the inner element to use `height:100%` instead of `max-height:100%`, will not trigger the scrollbar in Opera.

Other browser such as Chrome, Firefox or IE, does not display scrollbar in neither scenarios.

**I am wondering if this is a bug in Opera (appear in both ver.11 and 12), or just an undefined scenario in w3c spec?**

(it might seem counter-intuitive to have overflow:auto parent with max-height children, but the setup is actually quite useful for things like javascript scrolling, Opera's behaviour cause unexpected height of child element to be reported, thus breaking the custom scroll)

Comment: If you zoom out, the scrollbar appears in the other browsers as well. A [changelog](http://www.opera.com/docs/changelogs/windows/1150b/) may be the reason: `Spatial navigation in an overflow:hidden box not scrolling the box`

Answer (score 1):

> If you zoom out, the scrollbar appears in the other browsers as well. A [changelog](http://www.opera.com/docs/changelogs/windows/1150b/) may be the reason: Spatial navigation in an overflow:hidden box not scrolling